# Alternative to this if statement

Tags: c#

This might seem obvious, I'm currently using an if statement which isn't very useful in the current context. Multiple statements can be true and need to run(Multiple check boxes can be selected). I could rewrite it to include every possible combination in the statements but this doesn't seem efficient.  Do I need to use a different type of statement such as a switch?

```
   if (objFileAAGFlags.LocationStandard == true)
    {
        cbxLocationStandard.Checked = true;
        cbxLocationInsideM25.Checked = false;
        cbxLocationNorthScotland.Checked = false;
        cbxLocationNorthernIreland.Checked = false;
    }
    else if (objFileAAGFlags.LocationInsideM25 == true)
        {
            cbxLocationStandard.Checked = false;
            cbxLocationInsideM25.Checked = true;
            cbxLocationNorthScotland.Checked = false;
            cbxLocationNorthernIreland.Checked = false;
        }
    else if (objFileAAGFlags.LocationNorthScotland == true)
    {
        cbxLocationStandard.Checked = false;
        cbxLocationInsideM25.Checked = false;
        cbxLocationNorthScotland.Checked = true;
        cbxLocationNorthernIreland.Checked = false;
    }
    else if (objFileAAGFlags.LocationNorthernIreland == true)
    {
        cbxLocationStandard.Checked = false;
        cbxLocationInsideM25.Checked = false;
        cbxLocationNorthScotland.Checked = false;
        cbxLocationNorthernIreland.Checked = true;
    }
    else
    {
        cbxLocationStandard.Checked = false;
        cbxLocationInsideM25.Checked = false;
        cbxLocationNorthScotland.Checked = false;
        cbxLocationNorthernIreland.Checked = false;
    }
```

Comment: Yo should simply do `cbxLocationStandard.Checked =objFileAAGFlags.LocationStandard` and  so on of other checboxes. You don't need all these if-else

Comment: Does multiple conditions can be true?

Comment: @CodeNotFound "Multiple statements can be true and need to run(Multiple check boxes can be selected)"

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto thanks :) I don't know why I missed that sentence :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that multiple checkboxes can be selected at the same time, so you can remove all your `if` statements and just assign the values from the flags themselves:

```
cbxLocationStandard.Checked = objFileAAGFlags.LocationStandard;
cbxLocationInsideM25.Checked = objFileAAGFlags.LocationInsideM25;
cbxLocationNorthScotland.Checked = objFileAAGFlags.LocationNorthScotland;
cbxLocationNorthernIreland.Checked = objFileAAGFlags.LocationNorthernIreland;
```

*Note*: if any of the properties is a `bool?`, you would have to do the following instead:

```
cbxLocationStandard.Checked = objFileAAGFlags.LocationStandard == true;
// OR
cbxLocationStandard.Checked = objFileAAGFlags.LocationStandard.GetValueOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 3):

Here you go

```
cbxLocationStandard.Checked = objFileAAGFlags.LocationStandard == true;
cbxLocationInsideM25.Checked = objFileAAGFlags.LocationInsideM25 == true;
cbxLocationNorthScotland.Checked = objFileAAGFlags.LocationNorthScotland == true;
cbxLocationNorthernIreland.Checked = objFileAAGFlags.LocationNorthernIreland == true;
```

Comment: I removed my last comment because you fixed that, but your last update made it pretty bad, not sure at all the need for those `== true`

Comment: question was to refactor already working code. according to the OPs' code only one `true` is possible. So, your previous version was correct I believe. But now it is not. P.s. DownVote is not mine

Comment: @DmitryPavliv but in the question OP says _Multiple statements can be true and need to run(Multiple check boxes can be selected)_

Comment: Not sure why you got the downvotes, this seems to be the answer (based on what OP asked and not making assumptions).

Comment: This also seems to be a correct answer (although can be improved by removing the redundant `== true` parts).

Comment: @fubo What makes you think that they are? The default would be that that are NOT nullable unless otherwise stated.

Comment: @MatthewWatson **1.** I don't know it so I make the `== true` comparrison - my code works in both cases **2.** both ways are valid and thats also a question of the personal taste and OP initially used in his code so why should I remove it?

Comment: Well it's no longer in an `if` statement - it's now a plain assignment. In such cases, using the `== true` makes the code harder to read. Inside an `if` statement, then it's more debatable - but it's no longer an `if`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
        cbxLocationStandard.Checked = false;
        cbxLocationInsideM25.Checked = false;
        cbxLocationNorthScotland.Checked = false;
        cbxLocationNorthernIreland.Checked = false;
```

at the start, than inside each if just do:

```
   if (objFileAAGFlags.LocationInsideM25)
        {
            cbxLocationInsideM25.Checked = true;
        }
```

This is the minimal code change required to make it work, however because more than one option is available you can asign them directly:

```
 cbxLocationInsideM25.Checked = objFileAAGFlags.LocationInsideM25
```

For each individual flag.